# Running inferior lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp

After installing emacs and attempting to `run-lisp`, I get

```
Searching for program: No such file or directory, lisp
```

Then, after trying to run lisp again, a new `inferior-lisp` buffer opens, but if I try entering anything in, I get:

```
Output file descriptor of inferior-lisp<1> is closed
```

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set `inferior-lisp-program` variable. Be careful 'cos some Lisps expect the core to be specified in the command-line or reside in a current directory (especially if you're on Windows).

If you're a newbie and just want to get familiar with lisp there is a built-in Elisp interpreter. Run `M-x ielm` to get it.

Comment: I use this line in my config `(setq inferior-lisp-program (executable-find "sbcl"))`. This obviously depends on sbcl.

Answer (score 1):

From the info page on emacs (31.11 Running an External Lisp):

To run an inferior Lisp process, type `M-x run-lisp'.  This runs the
program named`lisp', the same program you would run by typing `lisp'
as a shell command, with both input and output going through an Emacs
buffer named`*lisp*'.

It look like you do not have an program in your path that is call "lisp".